# 3D scan gives a flat mesh, how do I create a solid from this?

Tags: mesh, 3d-printing

I just 3d-scanned part of my front bumper and after a bit of cleanup this is the result. This is just a flat mesh and thus it's difficult to use in Fusion 360 so my thought was to use Blender to turn it into a solid but I am unsure how to do this. An idea I've had is to somehow cut this shape out of a cube, could this be done and if so, how?

[image: 3D-scan, just a flat mesh]

Comment: solidify modifier?

Comment: @Chris Sadly doesn't work at all, provides veeery glitchy results

Comment: Try selecting all in edit mode (face select mode), right click and select "extrude faces along normals". You can move your mouse to change the extrusion direction/depth or you can input a (positive or negative) numeral distance value. If this gives wonky results, you may want to turn on _face orientation_ in overlays to make sure your faces are all pointing in the same relative direction.

Comment: It looks like it is pre-solidified by the 3D scanner. You may have to delete the back facing side and bordering edges before you can re-solidify.